# Is there a standart way of describe a process

Tags: style

I would like to describe a process such as  production of fruit juice. When I started my sentence which explains a process and then what the best way to explain its purpose is in terms of  verb and modal preference in a formal writing.

> First of all fruits are harvested and then they are sorted so that the
>   rotten ones **will** be removed.
>
> Firs of all fruits are harvested and then they are sorted so that the
>   rotten ones **would** be removed.
>
> First of all fruits are harvested and then they are sorted so that the
>   rotten ones **can** be removed.
>
> First of all fruits are harvested and then they are sorted so that the
>   rotten ones **are** removed.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you're asking. Are you asking if these sentences are grammatically correct? Clearly written? Or are you looking for some model of how to describe a process? In what sense?

Comment: The third example, using "can", sounds best to me. The sorting makes it possible to remove the rotten ones. The fourth example would also sound OK but since "fruits" is in the plural, use "are" not "is". By the way, "get ridden of" is incorrect here. It should be "got rid of". Even that sounds overly colloquial, and some people think that no sentence should end with a preposition, so I recommend following the example in Tave's answer and using "remove".

Comment: This question is unclear; if it's meant to be a general critique, I'm sorry but those aren't on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I would break it into two sentences such as: All fruits are harvested. The rotten ones are removed.

There isn't a formula that I am aware of, but I would recommend trying not to use 'then', using the present tense and using a third person perspective.

I would also recommend using a grammar checker such as [Language Tool](https://www.languagetool.org/) to show you where there are problems.